# Supporting extra LEDs on laptop keyboard

Tags: linux, keyboard, hp

My laptop, an HP Elitebook 745 G6, has some extra keys on its keyboard: a presentation key, a call answer key, and a hangup key.  Each of these keys has an LED on it.

Where might I begin to look to be able to control these LEDs from Linux?  The keys themselves work fine (after some fiddling with `setkeycodes`).

I've checked `/sys/class/leds`, that only contains num lock, scroll lock, caps lock, mute, mic mute.  I've explored the GPIO pins: there's one for the wifi LED, but nothing for these.  I've looked at `evtest` and haven't found anything there either.  The `hp_wmi` module is loaded, but doesn't expose any LEDs.  `xset led` does nothing with them.

Are there any other avenues that I've missed that I can investigate?